# Elasticsearch custom score if/then on non-numeric field

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I have a boolean field in my index. Is it possible to multiply the document score by some amount if it is true? as a follow up, is it possible to do this within the custom score _script field?

Comment: doc['abc'].value == 'T' ? 1 : 0

Comment: If you solved you might want to add your own answer and accept it. Otherwise can you please tell us what you tried?